# Paros is not running

Tags: parosproxy

I installed Paros. At first, it worked fine. However, from the second start, Paros will start and automatically turn off after a few seconds. I also tried to reinstall but the installer will automatically turn off. Why is that?

Window 10 64bit
I install 32bit java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason for using Paros? Its not been updated for over 10 years.

You'll be much better off using OWASP ZAP, which was forked from Paros in 2010, is free, open source and is very actively maintained: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/